# Use JBIG compression, Matlab, compression of a bit stream

Tags: matlab, image-processing, compression, jbig2

I'm having trouble with implementing a JBIG compression of a array of bits.

I want to do JBIG compression, as found here: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/jbigkit/

So I have downloaded the kit into my Matlab workspace and added it to the build path. I am new to Matlab, can anyone explain what I am meant to do from here to get it to work?

thanks

Comment: Did the files you downloaded not contain some sort of help files and/or demo code that shows how you use the code?  (Note: we should not need to go to another website and download the same code to be able to help you)

Comment: Thanks, I actually overlooked an examples folder, but the only thing it has a jbgtests file with 
% MATLAB code to generate test files that exercise a JBIG codec
width = 1200;
img = [];
for y=1:650;
    mx = ceil(y / 5);
    line = uint8(repmat(round(rand(1,mx)),1,ceil(width/mx))) == 1;
    img = [img ; line(1:width)];
end
imwrite(img, 'mx.png', 'PNG');
which doesn't really help me very much

Comment: @conapart3 - That toolkit looks like it has to be compiled and built, and it is a command-line toolkit.  As such, it doesn't look like you can integrate this with MATLAB unless you write a MEX wrapper for it.  You'll have to save the images using JBIG in the command-line and decompress using the command-line as well.  Either way, unless you write a MEX wrapper to interface the code directly with MATLAB, you can't bring this into MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks rayryeng, I actually spent the whole day trying to figure this out the hard way hahaha!:S I installed a C Compiler, compiled it all, but had no joy. So I found that there is a downloadable toolbox called "toolbox-wavelet" on the matlab file exchange that has the function 'perform-jbig-compression' along with the relevant C-code compression files. It took me a while to get it to work as I realised I had to add the DLLs used by the C code to the WINDOWS path rather than the 'ADD PATH' option in matlab.